# Is "You are so beautiful girl" incorrect?

Tags: grammar

> You are so beautiful girl.

I have read/used this sentence and it looks okay to me.

Nevertheless, the grammar rule of 'placement of adjective' says that *After how/so/too, the adjectives go **before** a/an* as in *"She's too polite a girl to refuse."*

Having this said,

> You are *so beautiful **a** girl* -is correct!

What do you think?

Comment: Can you please provide more context as to where you have read this sentence. If you confirm you copied properly or context makes the sentence plausible, I'll undo my downvote.

Comment: My first reactions: *You are so beautiful girl* sounds wrong. *You are so beautiful a girl* sounds fine. And it gave me a strange feeling to say *You are a so beautiful girl*, immediately I had to change it to *You are a very beautiful girl*, though I'm not sure exactly why.

Comment: Unfortunately, nobody understood this question! The question is clear - I **thought** that -you are so beautiful girl (It's my sentence, NO reference) is okay. But then Swan mentions that there should be **a** - You are so beautiful **a** girl is correct. But it looks a bit off to me. What do you think?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Source is missing, but no worries. Here are the situations that could be relevant here.

> You are so beautiful, girl

"Girl" is used as a term of endearment, or in support, most likely from one woman to another.

> You are so beautiful a girl

Is correct, but sounds horrible to me! It sounds quite forced. This would be better:

> You are such a beautiful girl

And therefore wins as my preferred option.

I think there is likely an error with the original sentence, as it seems a tad ungrammatical to me.

Comment: The source is **Swan's Practical use of English**

Comment: Blimey! Well, I stick by my answer. I don't the original sentence, and I think "such a" is a great way to make it better.

Comment: @MaulikV. Swann is not so bad generally. Can you check again if there's no comma missing, as JMB suggests, or if you copied the sentence entirely, it could be "You are so beautiful girl (that I can't help thinking of you) for example..."

Comment: @Laure That sentence is NOT from Swan. I said that sentence looks absolutely okay to me but if I go by that book, it says adding **a** before a noun. That's what the question is. Two downvotes! Eh!

Comment: @MaulikV. sorry but you didn't make it very clear. I'll rephrase my comment.

Comment: @JMB I think the reason why it doesn't work well in "she's so beautiful a girl" is because, as Swan states, this use of "so" is formal. If "girl" is replaced with "person" (so that the sentence sounds more formal), then "she's so beautiful a person" sounds better to me.

Comment: @MaulikV From which entry exactly that you referred to, because if you're quoting entry 14, it's "After *as, how, so, too* and *this/that* meaning *so*, adjective go before *a/an*. This structure is common in a formal style." Btw, I believe you meant the book *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Yes...that's the entry confusing me.

Comment: @Nico. I agree with what you say. Maulik - the "how, so, too" plus "a/an" is pretty formal. For future readers, I think my answer provides a pretty common solution to this type of situation, but as Nico commented, "person" could work. I stand by my "such a beautiful" as the best solution though.

Comment: +1.  I agree that "you are so beautiful a girl" is grammatical, if quite formal sounding.  I also agree that the version with "such a" sounds better.  For that matter, I also agree that Swan's book is good.  Agreement all around! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental issue is that 'girl' is a singular countable noun. In English a singular countable noun must be preceded by a determiner (in 99.99% of cases - there are two or three exceptions). 'You are so beautiful girl' does not have a determiner and does not fall into any of the exceptions, so it is wrong. 'You are so beautiful a girl' has a determiner, so is not (immediately) 'wrong' (on that account, at least - it may be for other reasons).

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, I agree that ”You are such a beautiful girl" sounds Ok.

I think that it would also be fine to say:

”You are very beautiful, girl"

When I hear "so", I expect a second statement which should begin with "that"... something like:

"You are so beautiful that I can't stop staring at you."

Comment: Just remember that most women, young and old, absolutely don’t appreciate being called “girl”. “You are so beautiful, girl” (or woman) won’t make you friends.